# Convert path to querystring and preserve initial querystring parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an incoming path like this

`http://acme.com/product/xxxxxx?utm_campaign=yyyyy`

I need to convert this to

`$http://acme.com/product?id=xxxxx&utm_campaign=yyyyy`

The number of parameters are arbitrary, so there may be 1, none or 10.

I have these .htaccess rules, which are close to working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?product/(.*?)/?$ /product?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The problem with this code is that the result ends up with two question marks.  For instance:

`http://acme.com/product/xxxxxx?utm_campaign=yyyyy`

becomes

`http://acme.com/product?id=xxxxxx?utm_campaign=yyyyy`

instead of

`http://acme.com/product?id=xxxxxx&utm_campaign=yyyyy`

Comment: It shouldn't. Try adding the `DPI` flag to your rule and remove the leading slash from your rule and the substitution.